# jQuery custom plugin 'change'-event is not being processed immediatly

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to build a very lightweight live search as a jQuery custom plugin.

What I want to achieve is that I call `$('input[type="text"].js_test').liveSearch(successCallBackFn);` on any `input[type='text']` and the data received from the `$.ajax()` call is being handeled by `successCallBackFn()`. In my test case I am simply adding it to the DOM.

```
<input class="js_test" type="text" name="test" value="" data-identifier="testajax" />


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js_test').liveSearch(mySuccessCallback);
});

//callback
function mySuccessCallback($liveSearchTrigger, response) {
    $('body').append(response.results_html);
}

//jQuery plugin
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.liveSearch = function(successCallbackFn) {

        var $liveSearchTrigger = $(this);

        $liveSearchTrigger.change(function() {
            $.ajax({
               url: '/ajax/livesearch/' + $(this).data('identifier'),
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'JSON',
               data: {
                   search: this.value
               },
               success: function(response) {
                   if (response.success) {
                        if (typeof(successCallbackFn) !== 'undefined') {
                            return successCallbackFn($liveSearchTrigger, response);
                        }
                   }
               }
            });
        });

        return this;
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Now when I type something into the input, nothing happens. (Firefox) Developer Tools show me that no XHR is taking place **until** I click the browser window again, then the `POST` is being processed and the data in `response.results_html` is being appended to the `$('body')` element.

When I add

```
$('.js_test').change(function() { 
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

to the `$(document).ready()` function's scope, any change is being registered instantly.

Why is the `POST` and its resulting `$('body').append()` only triggered after I refocus the browser window (by clicking into it) and how do I achieve that the `$liveSearchTrigger.change()` is being triggered instantly when typing into the input?

I am sure I am missing something very minor hence this is my first attempt in making a custom jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change event is only triggered when the element loses focus on text inputs.

I would recommend rereading: https://api.jquery.com/change/

And also change your call to .change() call to something like **keypress()** or **keydown()**

If you use those methods everytime a key is pressed within the input you can assume its value has changed and carry out your livesearch.

Keypress documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Note: For performance you will probably want to add in a check that the key pressed is not a modifier, ie. shift or escape

Comment: Oh gash, I knew it had to be something tiny and stupid ;)

Comment: The exact same thing caught me out when implemented an autocomplete once so it gets us all! Glad i could help!